# Wordpress Includes mejs 404 error

Tags: theme-development, jquery, core, include

I have an issue with NewRelic reporting a number of 404 errors which all stem from the WP includes mejs

Example of the 404 error
site.com/mejs.hebrew
& site.com/mejs.dutch

Has this occurred for anyone else or anyone got an idea on why this might be occurring?